# When Drupal Upload Maxes PHP Limit

Tags: 7, files

It seems when I try to save a node with FileField populated with a file that exceeds the PHP limit, Drupal just returns to `node/add` without any error messages.

This is bypassing the AJAX upload.

Ideally, there should be an error message that tells the user why they are being returned to a blank form.

I tried this on pretty-much fresh install too and I'm still getting this behavior.

Comment: If you use the standard Javascript upload widget, this message is shown: "An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (X MB) that this server supports." Why do you need to bypass AJAX upload?

Comment: If @FreeRadical got it right and you bypass AJAX upload on purpose, you have some really weird bug. What's in your JS console?

Comment: @FreeRadical I don't need to bypass AJAX; it's an option given by Drupal- users can select a file and then just save the node without clicking the `upload` button which is a legitimate way to create or edit a node.

Comment: You're right.  I never knew you could do that.  I am able to reproduce the behaviour you report (saving the node fails without any error message or warning). This is obviously a bug.  We don't fix bugs here, so you need to take it to the core [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal).

Comment: @FreeRadical Thanks. Issue filed at https://drupal.org/node/2239313